# Django Help! Form with method post is not callin the action correctly with django url tag need help understanding why this doesn not work?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

While trying to create a simple search form using method="POST" and action linking to a url that should trigger a view to render a different template I have come across it not working all it does is tag on the csrf to my index url and acts like I am using GET not POST any thoughts on why?

HTML URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/bugtracker/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=jdGcvGb8pioQutLhDOL8y6zbK7DW6XSErTYQ8zHOI8W1fAXf8V6NFoFmzXRIvC3d&searched=
```

View:

```
    @login_required(login_url='login_register')
    def search_site(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        context = {
            'searched': searched
        }
        return render(request, 'bugs/search_site.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'bugs/search_site.html')
```

URL:

```
    path('search_site/', views.search_site, name='search_site'),
```

Search bar template:

```
    <div class="input-group">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'search_site' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." name="searched">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Search result template:

```
{% extends 'bugs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
        {% if searched %}
        <h4 class="mt-4">results for {{ searched }}</h4>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried changing method to get, I have tried to change my url and my view to no avail. and removing crf just makes the url tag a ? into the index it seems like it is not calling anything at all.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct code / submitting the correct form? Perhaps you have some JavaScript intercepting your form submission and sending a GET request?

Comment: I was looking at the correct code but for some reason while writing it out I preemptively put a form tag above my input group div, and then I forgot about it so when I made the new form tag closer to the actual input and button it caused there to be a form with in  a form witch will always Call a GET not a POST, I fixed it and it is now running smoothly thank you for your comment it made me really look at it witch sometimes I need lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide two suggestions, first to render outside the else condition, and the second to see `searched` has any value or not by printing it.

```py
@login_required(login_url='login_register')
def search_site(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        print(f"searched value --> {searched}")
        context = {
            'searched': searched
        }
        return render(request, 'bugs/search_site.html', context)
    return render(request, 'bugs/search_site.html')
```

Search result template:

```html
{% extends 'bugs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
        {% if searched %}
        <h4 class="mt-4">results for {{ searched }}</h4>
        {% else %}
        <p>No value has come.</p>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I also think it should be another template in `POST` Method check it, you have provided `search_site.html` may be it is something like `search_result.html`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer/suggestions I did end up following both suggestions to no avail but it did make me look at the code names a bit more and check all my calls, found out that I was being stupid and and a form with in a form witch seems to always calls GET so essentially it was never calling my view in the first place and thus not triggering the print or rendering the new page now it is and all seems to be working, I will mark this as the answer how ever due to the fact that It did help with trouble shooting steps that made me think about it a bit more.